# Creating multiple bean instances of a class with different property values in spring configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, javabeans, spring-bean

I am creating multiple bean instances of a class with different property values in spring configuration.
For example:

```
<bean id="myBeanA" class="MyClass">
  <property name="identifier" value="A"/>
</bean>

<bean id="myBeanY" class="MyClass">
  <property name="identifier" value="B"/>
</bean>
```

I am new to Spring framework and I am just curious to know the pros and cons to doing this.

Comment: Why has your second bean an other class name? At now you create 2 beans with different classes ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

of course you can (as you already show - ignoring typo). Pros/Cons? None, you just do it if it make sense for you...

```
<bean id="primaryService" class="MyService">
  <property name="url" value="http://domain1/"/>
</bean>

<bean id="premiumService" class="MyService">
  <property name="url" value="http://domain2/"/>
</bean>
```

E.g. you can have two instances of the same service type, but accessing different remote URL. You can use `premiumService` only for paying customers as kind of quality of service (e.g. `domain2` is stronger machine)